# Eclipse error : cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, constructor

So I was doing this exercise that simulates car instruments. There are three classes in total : `FuelGauge`, `Odometer` and `CarInstrumentSimulator` (the one with the main method). The two first ones each have a constructor that I have defined. However whenever I type this in the `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CarInstrumentSimulator carInstrumentSimulator = new CarInstrumentSimulator();

    FuelGauge fuel = carInstrumentSimulator.new FuelGauge();
    Odometer odometer = carInstrumentSimulator.new Odometer(0, fuel);
```

I always get a CarInstrumentSimulator.FuelGauge cannot be resolved into a type error in eclipse(and same for the Odometer), however I got this line of code from the correction detailed in the website I got the exercise from (https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/exercises/car-instrument-simulator/)
I am very new to java and coding in general, so I was wondering :
1) what does this syntax mean:

```
    FuelGauge fuel = carInstrumentSimulator.new FuelGauge();
```

2) why is there a problem with this syntax?

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Why are you labeling this an "Eclipse error"? This has nothing to do with Eclipse and all to do with bad Java syntax. Are you nesting classes for some reason? If so, don't -- each class should go into its own file. Please post more pertinent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a typo in the [source](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/exercises/car-instrument-simulator/). Try this instead:

```
FuelGauge fuel = new FuelGauge();
Odometer odometer = new Odometer(0, fuel);
```

There is no sensible answer to this question ...

> what does this syntax mean :
>   `FuelGauge fuel = carInstrumentSimulator.new FuelGauge();`

... because the line in question is gibberish ;)

Valid method invocation on a Java object (such as `carInstrumentSimulator`) would require dot notation, the method name and opening and closing brackets e.g. `carInstrumentSimulator.doSomething()` but the above code does not have the opening and closing brackets, uses the word `new` which is not a valid Java method name (since it is a reserved keyword) and `new` is followed by `FuelGauge()` which makes the whole thing uninterpretable.

More details on Java method construction [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

If `FuelGauge` was declared inside `CarInstrumentSimulator` then this syntax would be valid:

```
new CarInstrumentSimulator.FuelGauge();
```

Similarly, if `CarInstrumentSimulator` exposed a creator method for `FuelGauge` then this syntax would be valid:

```
carInstrumentSimulator.newFuelGauge();
```

But this syntax isn't valid in any circumstances: `carInstrumentSimulator.new FuelGauge();`.

Comment: Thanks :D but I think whoever wrote this "correction" wanted to create an object from the CarInstrumentSimulator and that would hold characteristics initialized by both FuelGauge and Odometer classes constructors, that's why I thought there were some type of syntax to do so which I am still wondering about ^^

Comment: I've updated the answer in an attempt to address your last comment. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok thank you so much :) Just one last question: what is exactly a creator method?

Comment: The term "creator method" is not a formal term, it just means "a method which creates an object" i.e. instead of using a constructor like so: `new Foo()`, you might call a method `someBuilder.createFoo()` which internally just calls `new Foo()`. You could search for details on "factory pattern" and "builder pattern" to give you more context on that.